# How can i add a condition in hookBackOfficeHeader to my own prestashop module?

Tags: php, module, prestashop

I tried sending to my module prestashop addons. I got a message "Technical validation has been declined". This message contain the

**You need to add a condition in hookBackOfficeHeader to include your file only the pages that you want.**

My hookBackOfficeHeader hook is:

```
public function hookBackOfficeHeader()
{
    $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'views/css/back.css');
    $this->context->controller->addJquery();
    $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'views/js/back.js?v=1.0');
}
```

I need to use this css and js files just product edit page and module configuration page. How can i add a condition for this pages?

Regards

Answer (score 4):

There is many ways, I'll write the most easy:

```
public function hookBackOfficeHeader()
{
    if(
        (Tools::getValue('controller') == 'AdminProducts' AND Tools::getValue('id_product')) 
        OR 
        (Tools::getValue('controller') == 'AdminModules' AND
         (Tools::getValue('configure') == YOURMODULENAME OR Tools::getValue('module_name') == YOURMODULENAME)
        )
    ){
        $this->context->controller->addCSS($this->_path.'views/css/back.css');
        $this->context->controller->addJquery();
        $this->context->controller->addJS($this->_path.'views/js/back.js?v=1.0');
    }
}
```